# tutorial theme background color not working

Tags: ios, swiftui

Trying to follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/creating-a-card-view) iOS dev tutorial.

When I get to step 7 it the code does not change the background color as it is supposed to.

Quote "Step 7
Add a Color property named mainColor that creates a color using the enumeration’s rawValue.
This property initializes a color from the asset catalog."

Here is the code from the theme file:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Theme: String {
    case bubblegum
    case buttercup
    case indigo
    case lavender
    case magenta
    case navy
    case orange
    case oxblood
    case periwinkle
    case poppy
    case purple
    case seafoam
    case sky
    case tan
    case teal
    case yellow
    
    var accentColor: Color {
            switch self {
            case .bubblegum, .buttercup, .lavender, .orange, .periwinkle, .poppy, .seafoam, .sky, .tan, .teal, .yellow: return .black
            case .indigo, .magenta, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
            }
        }
    var mainColor: Color {
        Color(rawValue) // This line not working
    }
}
```

if I change the code to:

```
    var mainColor: Color {
        return .red
    }
```

The background changes to red as I would expect.

Code from View File is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    let scrum: DailyScrum
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(scrum.title)
                .font(.headline)
                .accessibilityAddTraits(.isHeader)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Label("\(scrum.attendees.count)", systemImage: "person.3")
                    .accessibilityLabel("\(scrum.attendees.count) attendees")
                Spacer()
                Label("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes)", systemImage: "clock")
                    .accessibilityLabel("\(scrum.lengthInMinutes) minute meeting")
                    .labelStyle(.trailingIcon)
            }
            .font(.caption)            
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)

    }
}

struct CardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var scrum = DailyScrum.sampleData[0]
    static var previews: some View {
        CardView(scrum: scrum)
            .background(scrum.theme.mainColor) // Here is were theme is called
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 400, height: 60))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same question: [Apple's SwiftUI tutorial code doesn't display view contents in homemade copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415292/apples-swiftui-tutorial-code-doesnt-display-view-contents-in-homemade-copy)

You should download the project files first, and import the **assets** folder from StartingProject.

**Note in apple docs:**
[image]

**Assets folder location:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to download **Assets.xcassets** if you are not using the started project and starting fresh by creating new project. This colder contains Icon assets and required Colors for the app.

Answer (score 0):

`Color(rawValue)` (where `rawValue` is a `String`) will only work if you have the color with the name `rawValue` in your assets catalog.

To make it work, you can modify your `mainColor` like this:

```swift
var mainColor: Color {
  switch self {
    case .purple:
      return .purple
    case .red:
      return .red
    // Etc.
  }
}
```

Of course, this won't work with things like `.bubblegum`, because `Color` doesn't have such standard colors–you should create them yourself in your assets.